# Wordpress plugin for user registration and posting a status

Tags: wordpress, user-registration

I am working on a website which is based on Wordpress. I want to make such a system which any user can register and login. And then he/she can post and change his/her post whenever he/she wants. How can I make it? Which plugin should I use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

For registration standart WordPress signup forms can be used.

For user posting, you can use WP User Frontend, which I previously used and liked. There is also a pro version with much more capability(never used pro version).

Free version:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/

Pro version:
http://wedevs.com/plugin/wp-user-frontend-pro